# Why CSS3 transition do no work more than one time

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, transition

i'm trying to find out and fix why the css3 transition only works properly once and then the transition doesn't work after that, it's a different animation from jQuery. Has anyone seen it before? Please tell me why and thanks in advance!

[here is my code.](http://jsfiddle.net/4TxqZ/4/)

Comment: You are entering the domain of [CSS Animations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/). (Which has a nice little thing called `animation-iteration-count:infinite`.)

Comment: hi ACJ, thanks for your comment but do you have a look in  http://jsfiddle.net/4TxqZ/4/
i'm using transition not animation property. All i want here is find out why when transition animation just run once when i click other tab and click back, it do not run anymore, it just show chart.

Comment: It will run again on a new page load, not when you click an other browser tab and go back, that's obvious.

Comment: hi Han, i got that, but when click to other tab, i set the chart back to it started position with this function resetLocalize() {
        $(".bar1.localize").stop().css({ bottom: -180 });
        $(".bar2.localize").stop().css({ bottom: -215 });
        $(".bar3.localize").stop().css({ bottom: -225 });
    }
and when click back the tab, it should run animation again as logic with this function localize() {
        $(".bar1.localize, .bar2.localize, .bar3.localize").stop();
        $(".bar1.localize, .bar2.localize, .bar3.localize").css({ bottom: 0 });
    }
but it won't run again, just appear.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the .localize elements' css transitions are activating when the elements are not being displayed. if you remove "display: none !important;" from ".ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide", it works as it should (though you see both tabs).

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide
{
    display: none !important; // remove this line to see what I'm talking about
}
```

localize() imediately sets the bottom value to 0, and since the tab is hidden, there is no css transition animation. No transition means the bars are jumping straight up to "bottom: 0" without animating.

I've had success with combining localize() and resetLocalize(), and using a brief timeout to set the bottom css after the tab is visible again, like this:

```
function localize() {
    $(".bar1.localize").css({ bottom: -180 });
    $(".bar2.localize").css({ bottom: -215 });
    $(".bar3.localize").css({ bottom: -225 });

    setInterval(function(){
         $(".bar1.localize, .bar2.localize, .bar3.localize").css({ bottom: 0 });
    },1);
   ;
}
```

See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jtlowe/4TxqZ/11/